# How do I turn of this popupwindow after typing comma?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ajK.jpg)

This popup window showed up every time I typed comma.
I don't know how to turn off it.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VS Code go to settings
then in settings type `editor.hover.enable` and then uncheck the box apearing bellow. your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

This is called **IntelliSense** in vscode.

You can close it by adding the following code to your setting.json:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
```

You can alos refer to this [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) for more information about IntelliSense.